# Create bar chart with dc.js from already processed data stored in a dictionary

Tags: javascript, dictionary, visualization, dc.js

I have a dictionary of the number of messages sent for each person in a facebook conversation stored in a variable that looks like this:

```
data = {
"Person1": 55132,
"Person2": 3556,
"Person3": 4848,
"Person4": 21184,
"Person5": 4364,
"Person6": 20716,
"Person7": 51172
}
```

I want to make a bar chart with dc.js. I've seen examples where people make it work by creating crossfilter dimension. So far, here's what I've got:

```
var msgCountChart = dc.barChart("#msg-count-row-chart");

var ndx = crossfilter([data]);
authorDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return Object.keys(d);});
sumGroup = authorDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d;});

msgCountChart
        .width(300)
        .height(280)
        .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(Object.keys(data)))
        .y(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, Math.ceil(Math.max(...Object.values(data)) / 10000) * 10000]))
        .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
        .brushOn(false)
        .dimension(authorDimension)
        .yAxisLabel("Messages sent")
        .barPadding(0.1)
        .outerPadding(0.05)
        .group(sumGroup);

msgCountChart.render();
```

I based my code on this example which had a kind of similar data structure: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/examples/ordinal-bar.html

The data in `ndx` seems to be null. How can I put my data in the crossfilter instance to make it work?

Is there another simpler solution to make the bar chart?

Answer (score 0):

Crossfilter takes an array as input. You’ve got an object.

The [dimension constructor](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension) takes a function returning the key for each row. So your current setup gives you one row of data with an array of all the keys as its key. Probably not `null` but probably not what you want.

The easiest way to get an array from an object, if you’re targeting modern browsers, is [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). This will give you an array of `[key, value]` pairs.

So:

```
var ndx = crossfilter(Object.entries(data)),
  authorDimension = ndx.dimension(d => d[0]),
  sumGroup = authorDimension.group().reduceSum(d => d[1]);
```

You don’t usually need to set the domain of X and Y scales; using `.elasticX(true).elasticY(true)` will usually figure that out for you.

Comment: Hi @Jérémy, did this work? Glad to iterate on this answer if there are problems.